# Find the no of votes secured by the person?

Tags: percentages

> $5000$ voted in an election between two candidates.$14$% of the votes were invalid.The winner won by a margin approximately closer to $15$%.Find the number of votes secured by the person.

**MyApproach**

$5000$ . $43$/$50$ votes were valid.

Out of these Winner gets.approx $15$% ..I am confused how to used this equation

=>$5000$ . $43$/$50$=$4300$ . $3$/$20$=$645$  votes he won by a margin.

I am confused how to calculate the winning votes or losing votes?

> Can Anyone guide me what I am missing?

Comment: We have $0.1\%$ of the votes is $5$ votes. So we can get a margin of $15\%$, so how what do you mean with approximately closer to $15\%$?

Answer (score 0):

Well done: you are making good progress. The difference between the votes received by the two candidates is $645$.

So if the winner received $x$ votes, the loser must have received $x-645$ votes.

Total $x+x-645=4300$

$2x=4945$

$x=2472.5$

All of this is assuming that the margin of victory is the percentage of valid votes. It could be interpreted as being the percentage of total votes, in which case the difference is $750$ votes.